# Show like Pokémon, but with dice that have runes

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember there was a stone/wood golem, an ice bird, and a yellow robot, and the main villain uses a green bug and each monster is connected to the seal/rune.

Comment: This is very terse at the moment so could you take a look at [this anime ID guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) and the [general guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you watch this? Was it new at the time? Can you remember any plot elements or story lines?

Comment: Don't have enough detailed info to make an answer, but look at Yu-Gi-Oh Dungeon Dice Monsters. https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Dungeon_Dice_Monsters

Answer (score 4):

Maybe *Di-Gata Defenders* (2006).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831823/):

> Di Gata Defenders was a television show that aired throughout the years 2007 2009 in various different continents. The show consisted of 6 Protagonists. and various Antagonists. The Di Gata Defenders were 4 teenagers who were set to defend their realm of RaDos against all the forces of evil that wish to destroy the peace. The 4 Defenders; Melosa, Seth, Kara, and Erik were the first characters introduced. The 4 managed to gain two extra friends. One loyal friend, Rion who happens to be the youngest after Kara is finished off.Rion was made a defender. They also managed to make a on-off friendship with the damaged "son" of one of the antagonists, the sons name is Adam. Adam decided not to become a defender but instead sent out to search for his Bio parents.

You can see the dice covered in runes in the opening, as well as an ice dragon (not a bird), the yellow robot Robotus, and Kragus the rock giant.

---

Remembered from [Animated show about warriors who summon giant monsters using rocks covered in runes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/201531).

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.