# Cartoon with a girl who used boots to help her walk as she couldn't

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have been looking for this show for years now. It was a cartoon and was definitely on Netflix in 2009 or 2010. I remember there was a girl who I think was named Kira and her color was like aqua; she had an older brother whose color was red. Her legs didn't work so she had these boots that would help her walk. There was another girl who had like an ice bird and crystal necklaces and her color was blue. It was on another planet and there were robots and fallen civilizations.

Comment: Possibly you should add the "story_identification" tag to your question.

Comment: @Daarin Feel free to suggest an edit to this effect yourself in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by that was their colour? It was associated to them? They were that colour? etc. You can [edit] your question to add this information in. Also can you remember much of the story or plot elements? If so that would improve your chances of finding the answer.

Comment: Kinda sounds like the anime Guilty Crown, which had one handicapped girl who used robotic legs/boots to walk, and another girl with a crystal motif, but GC wasn't released until 2011 and I don't know if it was ever on Netflix.

Comment: The name escapes me but this sounds very similar to a PS2 game I used to play with my grandson

Comment: @DannyMcG: If RigaCrypto has the right answer, it might have been the DS game. https://digatadefenders.fandom.com/wiki/Games

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are searching for is the show https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/DiGataDefenders

[image]

It revolves around a group of kids that are part of the DiGata Defenders and they use special rocks that have the power to call upon the Primordial beings (aka animal/dinosaurs) to fight with them. The main character is starts to merge with his animal and is thinking of himself as a monster until someone helps him. One girl is unable to walk and has to use special boots and is always helped by her big brother.

Comment: If accepted, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201531/animated-show-about-warriors-who-summon-giant-monsters-using-rocks-covered-in-ru or vice versa.

Comment: Or, rather, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222248/cartoon-in-a-world-with-magic-stones-wielded-by-four-children-which-combine-to-b