# Cartoon in a world with magic stones wielded by four children which combine to become stronger, and can summon creatures

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Can you please help me find this animated show? There is a four member team with two boys and two girls. The boys can summon, with their stones, a rock golem (black wearing summoner) and a robot (orange wearing summoner). The two girls can summon something like a dragonfly (green wearing summoner, little girl) and the blue girl, I don't remember what she can summon.

I don't know where the animated show comes from.

By throwing the stone, they activate the stone's power. Each stone has different characters on it. When you don't match them correctly, you get a rebound effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, with the addition of the mention of throwing the stones, and that they had symbols inscribed on them, could it be *[Di-Gata Defenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders)*, a 2006 Canadian animation?

[image: Cover of the box for the first season, showing the kids casting runes]

> The humans, or RaDosians, of this world came from another planet. The planet's inhabitants were mostly dark-skinned, white haired individuals with glowing blue eyes. However, these people were struck with a life-destroying Toten'Ka virus, which had spread across their planet and killed millions. A small team of RaDos Primes (the name of these original aliens) escaped from their planet on a starship. These original humans eventually crash landed in RaDos. The sun and atmosphere of RaDos began to take effect on their physical forms, turning them into the people of the current timeline. But in doing so, they eventually exiled the original inhabitants, the Mortigarians, a race of amphibious snake-like humanoids to live under the sea. The people that live in RaDos as of the current timeline are the descendants of these first RaDosians.
>
> Before the humans arrived in this world, mystical beings called the Primordials roamed the realm. Their bodies used mystical energies as their life force. As they died, their life force leeched into the rocks of Di-Gata Mountains. Humans soon crash landed on the planet, caused by a stowaway creature named the Wrath-norak and a virus from their dying planet. Under Rados' sun, man's skin colour soon changed. Man was then able to mine the enchanted rocks found in the mountains, but were only able to recover energy from eight of the eleven sigils. Many rocks were mined by man, then carved into dice-like Di-Gata stones, and these were then carved with the sigil their power contained. From this point onward, anyone who used these stones were called stone casters or stone-slingers. It was believed that the first people who used these stones of power were called the Chi'Brek Tribe. This tribe was also the first tribe to document the arrival of the human race onto the planet.
>
> There are currently ten known power forms in RaDos called Sigils. These sigils take up energy forms inside of Di-Gata Stones. But because the power of one sigil isn't as strong as the other, multiple sigils must be used, creating Henges. This creates a far greater concentration of power. However, some sigils do not need to be formed into henges, due to the extreme power that is contained within them (Vitus and Nostrum Vitae).

**Opening Credits**

I previously provided this as an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201531/animated-show-about-warriors-who-summon-giant-monsters-using-rocks-covered-in-ru).

Comment: Ohhh, they are 5 not 4 XD. You are the best.

Answer (score 2):

Based off of the "two boys and two girls who can summon creatures", I submit *[Huntik: Secrets and Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)*:

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.[5] Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.

Found via a search for *cartoon summon magic stones, which brought up [Animated show with character who has a stone that summons creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186121/animated-show-with-character-who-has-a-stone-that-summons-creatures)

You can see some of the summons in this trailer:

Comment: It is another animated show. With throwing the stone they active the stone's power. Each stone with symbol has different characters. When you don't match correctly then you will get the rebound.