# Anime/cartoon featuring characters that had stone dice with powers. Aired on CN mid 2000s

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series, toonami

The characters used to throw ancient stone dice. When the dice/stone touched the ground, a shape or magical circle would appear. (I remember it was purple and seemed like dark energy; also the dice glowed because of that energy).
They used to carry the stone dice in a pouch. There was a fighting scene in a cave. That's all I remember.

For reference I'm going to attach a few similar picture that I've it's not the same but you can have a idea of what I'm trying to explain.
Thanks. [The power stone design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0G9a.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Di-Gata Defenders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831823/)*** (2006–2008)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders):

> *Di-Gata Defenders* is an animated series created by Greg Collinson that was produced by LuxAnimation and Nelvana Entertainment. The series follows the travels and adventures of six teenagers, part of an organization called the Di-Gata Defenders. Their mission as heroes is to defend RaDos against evil factions. The series aired for two seasons.

As shown in the video below, it does involve characters throwing glowing, dice-like cubes to the ground.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222248/cartoon-in-a-world-with-magic-stones-wielded-by-four-children-which-combine-to-b